# How to better draw connecting lines in a manually constructed family tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

After a few days of unsuccessful struggle with `genealogytree`, I've decided to manually draw a family tree with tikz.  I've two questions about the MWE below:

Can the double line connecting node nBob to nAlice be aligned with the top line of nBob ("Bob") instead of its vertical midpoint?

And is there a more efficient way of drawing the lines connecting the children than manually specifying all those coordinates?  I don't mind specifying the coordinates for the nodes (in fact, that's easier than trying to get `genealogytree` to place nodes reasonably). But it sure would be nice to say, draw the horizontal line and then connect it to the children nodes without having to specify the coordinates of the vertical connectors.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % How to align double line with "Bob" instead of vertical midpoint of (nBob)?
  \node[text width=2cm] (nBob) at (2,0) {\centering Bob\\the giant\par};
  \node (nAlice) at (6,0) {Alice};
  \draw[double] (nBob) -- (nAlice);

  \node (nBobby) at (1.5,-2) {Bobby};
  \node (nAlly)  at (4.5,-2) {Ally};
  \node (nOops)  at (7.5,-2) {Oops};

  % How to draw these lines more efficiently?
  \draw (4.25,0) -- (4.25,-1);
  \draw (1.5,-1) -- (7.5,-1);
  \draw (1.5,-1) -- (nBobby);
  \draw (4.5,-1) -- (nAlly);
  \draw (7.5,-1) -- (nOops);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Here is Ignasi's answer where I've introduced a new problem: Sally.  Sally is a child of Bob, but with a not-shown mother.  There are two issues (I figured out a horizontal alignment issue that I posted a moment ago.)

- The line from nBob to nSally passes through the label "the giant"
- I don't understand why `\draw (aux) -- (aux|-aux2) (aux2);` works

Enhanced MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm, label={[anchor=north, yshift=1mm]below:the giant}] (nBob) {Bob};
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm,right=4cm of nBob] (nAlice) {Alice};
  \draw[double] (nBob) -- coordinate[pos=.6] (aux) (nAlice);

  \node[below=of nBob] (nSally) {Sally};
  \node[right=of nSally] (nBobby) {Bobby};
  \node[right=of nBobby] (nAlly) {Ally};
  \node[right=of nAlly] (nOops) {Oops};

  \draw (nBob) -- coordinate[pos=0.75] (aux2) (nSally);
  \draw (aux) -- (aux|-aux2) (aux2); % don't understand this line
  \draw (nBobby) -- (nBobby|-aux2)-|(nAlly);
  \draw (nBobby) -- (nBobby|-aux2)-|(nOops);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is never necessary to specify intermediate coordinates when drawing orthogonal lines - it can all be done with `-|`, `|-` and the `calc` library. I do not understand your first question: Do you really want the double line to go at an angle from the top of nBob down to the middle of nAlice?

Comment: No, I want the double line horizontal, so that would mean aligning nBob so that it is lower than I have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, probably, better solutions, but this trick can solve the problem. Instead of using a `multiline` node, the second line is added as a label. This way `Bob` and `Alice` are aligned.

About positioning, I think it's better to use relative positioning with `positioning` library. And corners can be solved with `|-` or `-|` as @hpekristiansen suggested.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % How to align double line with "Bob" instead of vertical midpoint of (nBob)?
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm, label={[anchor=north, yshift=1mm]below:the giant}] (nBob) {Bob};
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm,right=4cm of nBob] (nAlice) {Alice};
  \draw[double] (nBob) -- coordinate (aux) (nAlice);

  \node[below=of aux] (nAlly) {Ally};
  \node[left=of nAlly] (nBobby) {Bobby};
  \node[right=of nAlly] (nOops) {Oops};

  % How to draw these lines more efficiently?
  \draw (aux) -- coordinate[pos=0.75] (aux2) (nAlly);
  \draw (nBobby) -- (nBobby|-aux2)-|(nOops);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Answer to updated question:**

To avoid de problem with the vertical line crossing "the giant", we can add a name to the `label` (every `label` is a `node`) and draw the line between the label and Sally.

About the *strange* line `\draw (aux) -- (aux|-aux2) (aux2);`. It means draw a line between coordinate `aux` and the intersection of a vertical line through `aux` and an horizontal line through `aux2`, and then place the pen again over `aux2`. This last movement is not necessary. It should be `\draw (aux)--(aux|-aux2);`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm, label={[anchor=north, yshift=1mm, name=giant]below:the giant}] (nBob) {Bob};
  \node[minimum width=1.5cm,right=4cm of nBob] (nAlice) {Alice};
  \draw[double] (nBob) -- coordinate[pos=.6] (aux) (nAlice);

  \node[below=of nBob] (nSally) {Sally};
  \node[right=of nSally] (nBobby) {Bobby};
  \node[right=of nBobby] (nAlly) {Ally};
  \node[right=of nAlly] (nOops) {Oops};

  \draw (giant) -- coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2) (nSally);
  \draw (aux) -- (aux|-aux2);% (aux2); % don't understand this line
  \draw (nBobby) -- (nBobby|-aux2)-|(nAlly);
  \draw (nBobby) -- (nBobby|-aux2)-|(nOops);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is terrific! But I've run into two more problems. If I want to draw a child directly below a labeled node (say nBob has another child and the mother is unknown), the vertical line goes right up to "Bob", passing through "the giant". Can such a line be restricted from passing through the label? There's also another alignment issue.  I've edited my question to illustrate.

Comment: @dedded I've update the answer trying to solve your doubts. I hope it helps.

Comment: Very much so, thanks! One final note, you can get some small vertical mis-alignment if some names have descenders (y, g, j, etc.) and some don't.  Should be able to resolve that with a `\strut` at each name.

Answer (score 1):

With `forest` package (for fun):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{node distance=17mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
    align=center,
    inner sep = 2pt,
% tree style
     child anchor = north,
             grow = south,
     forked edge,           
            l sep = 12mm,   
            s sep = 2mm,
         fork sep = 6mm,  
            }
%
[ ,coordinate, name=r
    [Ally]
    [Bobby,before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
    [Oops]
]
\node (B) [left =of r, align=center] {Bob\\ the gaint};
\node (A) [right=of r] {Allice};
\draw[double] (B) -- (A);
\draw (B) -- ++ (0,-1.2) node[below] {Sue};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about playing around with forest, but after frustration with genealogytree (I had planned on being done with this thing earlier in the week) I figured I'd do it with full manual placement.  May still look into forest in the future.